# Manejo de excepción al eliminar registro con llave foranea

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un formulario con un datagridview que se alimenta de una base de datos mysql, al eliminar un registro (fila) me marca la siguiente excepción:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`bd`.`usuarios`, CONSTRAINT `usuarios_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
> (`IdOficina`) REFERENCES `oficinas` (`IdOficina`))

La excepción es correcta debido a las claves foraneas entre las tablas usuarios y oficinas, pero como puedo enviarle al usuario otro mensaje más entendible en lugar del mensaje de excepcion, por ejemplo "No se puede eliminar el registro debido a que se esta utilizando"

Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando para manejar la excepcion.

```
try
{
    //Haz algo...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Usas Entity Framework o SQL puro?

Comment: Estoy utilizando SQL puro

Comment: Estas utilizando procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: no, estoy utilizando la sintaxis sql normal para eliminar un registro de sql.